# Opening xcode keeps adding back old certificates

Tags: xcode

I had certificate problems, so i deleted my certificates, invalidated them on the apple developer portal, and started again with new ones. The problem is, every time i open xcode, it adds the old ones back into the keychain, and then gives me the error of 'appears more than once in the keychain'. Anybody know how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to delete provisioning profiles also.

You can do this in **Organizer**. There select **Devices** at the top. Than on the left pane you have **Library** section and there you have **Provisioning profiles**. Delete all which you dont need and restart XCode (restart is maybe not needed, but we all know how XCode works :) ). Than install your new profiles and certificates.